# Model regarding optimization of merchandice loading and distribution - Python

Tags: python, model, libraries, logistics

I find myself with the next problem:
I have to load bottles into pallets and fill a track with those pallets. The bottles are the same size but of different brands.

After the track is full, the bottles are distributed to the clients in a sequence. Now the issue is that if the first client needs a bottle that was packed at the bottom of the pallet, you need to discharge the entire pallet, take the bottles, and pack the pallet again, which is pretty inefficient.

So the main issue is not to optimize the number of bottles that fit in the pallet, as they are equal, but how to organize them so the people who distribute the bottles can do their job efficiently. One method, for example, would be to place the first clients' orders at the top of the pallet, and the orders of the last clients at the bottom.

Now, I would love to know if there is a model already developed in python that does this, or if there is a helpful library to attempt this.
Thank you!